# Having an array of questions, I need to check if the user vote any answer inside each questions

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, symfony

I have a project built with Symfony + Mongodb as *backend* an Angular2 as *frontend*. I will try to explain my question as well as I could in order to get the best answer.

My entities are:

Question
Answer
Vote

Every question can have many answers and every answer many votes. A user can vote an answer (and only one) in each question.

Well. I have a controller that returns an array of questions for the home page

```
   public function getQuestions(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher) {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
        $questionRepo = $em->getRepository('ThisOrThisBaseBundle:Question');
        $categoryRepo = $em->getRepository('ThisOrThisBaseBundle:QuestionCategory');
        $page = $paramFetcher->get('page',1);
        $categoryId = $paramFetcher->get('categoryId',false);
        $category = ($categoryId) ? $categoryRepo->findOneById($categoryId) : false;
        $dev = $questionRepo->findQuestionsPaginated($category,$page-1);
        $view = View::create()->setData($dev->toArray(false));
        return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
    }
```

Nothing special. What I want is the following: for every question get if the user vote one of its answers, so I can display a label in the *frontend* marking the answer that the user voted.

My doubt is about the best option to do this. I thing about:

- Get all the questions, iterate through the questions array in php, and make a query for each question to obtain the vote (if exists)
- Because the questions array is hydrated, iterate with PHP looking for the vote.
- Maybe other option that doesn't come to my head.

Thanks

Comment: I think the best idea is to do that with many to one relations on your entities and in your repository like that : Question->getAnswers($user); iterate on answers to fill an array of answers and and after Answer->getVotes() to fill the final array Answer->getVotes()

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You should use Doctrine and implement a Many-To-One with a necessary methods for your problem. 
If for some reason You can't: 
Make a single query to the answers table joined with a given user's votes. Ask for everything where question_id is in [array] (array is an array of questions' id that you've already got). Once You receive the rows check for every question if its id is present in the rows that You've received from DB.